# Multi Language React DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to translate the component React DatePicker. But, I'm getting an error when trying to do this.

My code so far:

```
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from 'react-datepicker';

const MONTHSDATE = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'];
const DAYSDATE = ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'];

registerLocale('ptBR', {
        localize: {
            month: n => MONTHSDATE[n],
            day: n => DAYSDATE[n]
        },
        formatLong: {}
    });
    

<DatePicker
    selected={realizedDateFrom}
    onChange={(date) => setRealizedDateFrom(date)}
    placeholderText={translate.t("activity_report_realized_from")}
    className="MuiInputBase-root MuiFilledInput-root activity-report-datepicker"
    dateFormat={'dd/MM/yyyy'}
    showMonthDropdown
    showYearDropdown
    formatWeekDay={nameOfDay => nameOfDay.substr(0, 3)}
    locale={translate.t("datapicker_translate")} //using translate getting word 'ptBR' for portuguese and 'en' for english
/>
```

When I change the language, this code works well just when i pick the date from calendar...

[image: English Calendar]
[image: Portuguese Calendar]

But when I try to write/input from the keyboard I get this error

[image]

The source code from this component is --> Project: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `date-fns` for `ptBR`. (Basically, the error is because the calendar needs more translations than the one which you write).

So, the recommended is to use them from `date-fns`, one example would be:

```js
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { registerLocale } from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { en, ptBR } from "date-fns/locale";

registerLocale("ptBR", ptBR);
registerLocale("en", en);

export default function App() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = React.useState("ptBR");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Change the Language ({language})</h3>
      <DatePicker locale={language} />
      <button onClick={() => setLanguage("ptBr")}>ptBr</button>
      <button onClick={() => setLanguage("en")}>eng</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The example is running on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-browser-yfvg7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to do this work for Multi language, specifically in English and Portuguese. Your answer works, but only in portuguese

Comment: @RafaelBreno I just updated the answer with the 2 languages.

Comment: Thanks again @joseglego I see. But what I want is the same component can change your own language. In your solution you just create another component with English. I'm mean I want is just one component DatePicker and be able to change your language.

Comment: @RafaelBreno Edited one more time, you can change in the third calendar :)

Comment: Thanks mi lord... You just salve my life. But I still have a question how can I be able to put the months and the days like I already puted

Comment: Yes, for sure, instead of `<DatePicker locale={language} />`. you have to use: `<DatePicker selected={realizedDateFrom} onChange={(date) => setRealizedDateFrom(date)} placeholderText={translate.t("activity_report_realized_from")} className="MuiInputBase-root MuiFilledInput-root activity-report-datepicker" dateFormat={'dd/MM/yyyy'} showMonthDropdown showYearDropdown formatWeekDay={nameOfDay => nameOfDay.substr(0, 3)} locale={language} />`

Comment: @RafaelBreno Please remember to mark the answer as accepted and/or useful if it helped u